# What does addChild/removeChild do to memory in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory-management

I'm unclear on how memory works in Actionscript 3. I create a series of buttons and store the address to each of them in an array. Those buttons are used to play various music files, and I want the one that is playing to have a particular color (red) and the rest to be white.  I call the following code when the currently selected button is to be replaced by a different button:

```
removeChild(songSelectButton[currSong]);
var songSelWhite:Button = new Button(null, "images/TrackButtonNo.jpg", TRACK_SELECT_WIDTH, TRACK_SELECT_HEIGHT);
songSelectButton[currSong] = songSelWhite;
```

That allows the array to have the right buttons.  However, I am concerned about whether I am wasting memory. Does garbage collection take care of this, or do I need a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, garbage collection is pretty smart and can clean up whatever mess you make. But it can take its time getting around to it, and it can really tie up the CPU when it decides to do it's thing. So careful management of memory is valuable.

In your case, why create a new Button? You've got a Button already, and it looks like its already in the right spot and everything. Just change the image, any listeners, and any other properties that you really need to change. Then you won't have to worry about new buttons getting allocated and deallocated, and you won't even have to worry about a new layout being calculated.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking.  Will do it that way.